# Detect Browser Proxy Settings

Tags: firebreath

I'm new to Browser plugin development. I'm developing an plugin using Firebreath. The problem I am having is that when proxy settings is set only for the browser, some of our third party components is not able to connect to the internet.

In the documentation, there was a method [FB::BrowserHost::DetectProxySettings()](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/class+FB+BrowserHost+DetectProxySettings) which should map the proxy settings to a std::map variable but when I integrated this into the actual project the method would always return false and the map would always be empty.

Are there any specific conditions in which the browser proxy settings cannot be retrieved? or is the DetectProxySettings() method designed to only detect System proxy settings?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you provide a URL to the DetectProxySettings method? Which browsers are you on? What OS?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The URL was the issue. I'm using Windows with IE, Firefox and Chrome. Hoping to integrate the same for MAC 10.7+ as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, make sure you provide a URL.  Also note that in IE it will get the windows system proxy because the browser doesn't provide an API, so it isn't URL-specific, it's just grabbing the system proxy settings, and you may have issues if you need authentication for said proxy.  The API is there to basically do as much as can be done, but it's not perfect :-/